# Run a single operation in Google Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

How can I write into BigQuery a single row with the time the job started and what options (arguments) were used?

In other words, how can I convert a `List<String>` into a `PCollection<List<String>>` with 1 entry so it can output to a single row in BigQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understood correctly. I think you are looking for:

```
p.apply(Create.of(LINES)).setCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
```

Above will give you `PCollection<String>`

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/pcollection#creating-a-pcollection